# Prevent remote screen recording of android app programmatically

Tags: android, remote-access

I want to prevent remote screen recording of my app using third party apps like Anydesk, Quicksuppport, Teamviewer etc.

I have used below flag for activity :

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

but the above flag doesn't work for all devices.

Any other work around for preventing remote screen recording?

Answer (score 0):

The apps you mentioned are operating with either permission of `CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT` or `CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT`. Unfortunately, if they own `CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT`, then setting the `FLAG_SECURE` on your window has no effect from their viewpoint.

Sadly, I don't think there is a better (or more effective) way to achieve the desired behavior.

If you make your app a *device administrator*, then (on certain api levels) you will have the ability to [disable screen capturing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setScreenCaptureDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)) on the entire device, but setting this up is a lot of hassle, and it's probably not what you want to do in the first place.